# Why does /cdrom folder exist? Shouldn't it be /media/cdrom or /mnt/cdrom?

Tags: 10.10, directory

Can somebody explain the logic behind Ubuntu's cdrom folder in root? (/cdrom)

I recall it used to be /media/cdrom or /mnt/cdrom before (in different distros perhaps)?

thanks.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you referring to?

Comment: mmmm. I currently use Ubuntu 10.10 64 bit. I'm new to linux world as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `/mnt/` and `/media/` are common places to mount devices, the device location can be just about anywhere.  `/cdrom/` was probably chosen for either brevity or legacy support.

Answer (score 8):

If you do a detailed listing of the root directory, you will see that `/cdrom` is just a link to `/media/cdrom` - a shortcut for convenience.

```
$ ls -l /
total 120
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2010-11-11 01:23 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2010-10-21 18:51 boot
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    11 2009-11-19 09:25 cdrom -> media/cdrom
...
```

Comment: hmm. In my case it's an actual folder though. ..                       
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2010-11-12 01:50 cdrom

Comment: No, it is a link to a folder but it looks like a folder from the file manager. /cdrom and /media/cdrom are effectively the same place.

Comment: mmm...looks like a folder to me though.... Otherwise when you do $ ls -l command I would see something like this cdrom -> media/cdrom (which I don't see). And when you right click on it in Nautilus it says that it's a "folder" and not a "link to a folder".    What distro do you use?   I though I've messed up somehting myself, but then I've openede xubuntu 10.10 in VirtualBox - and there is cdrom folder as well.  But anyway - not a biggie:) Thanks for response

Comment: @Andre: I am using Ubuntu 10.10. No idea why your system would be different.

Comment: @HamishDowner This no longer holds true in Ubuntu 16.04. There is no symbolic link when drive is empty. It's just a regular empty directory as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

> > Andre

For me, it doesn't become a link until something is in /media/cdrom, and that's weird.

I'm sure there's a reason why this is done, most likely for "brevity or legacy support" but the linking/unlinking part is quite strange. In past versions of Ubuntu these folders were constantly linked (last I checked was Intrepid maybe)....

I'm presently trying to hunt down the script that does this black magic in order to discover it's dark secrets.